# Add logo cvlc player Raspberry pi 3B+ bullseye

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, vlc

I try to add a logo in vlc player launched by terminale

```
cvlc --fullscreen --no-osd --loop --file-caching 10000 --sub-source logo --logo-position 10 --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/logo-tv.png /home/pi/Desktop/php/scala.m3u
```

but I have this error

```
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 1.0.6-1682-g88158c836)
[00b5c7a0] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[623710a0] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[62549eb0] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
[62549eb0] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:mmal_vout module
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1)
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1)
[62542140] blend blend error: no matching alpha blending routine (chroma: YUVA -> MMAL)
```

If I use

```
--sub-filter logo --logo-position 10 --logo-file
```

I have no errors but the logo doesn't appear.
can you help me?
thanks

Comment: try adding an opacity value e.g. `vlc --sub-source logo --logo-x 10 --logo-y 10 --logo-file ./logo-stackoverflow.png --logo-opacity 100 test23.mp4`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony thanks. I try to reset vlc config `vlc --reset-config` and play `cvlc --sub-source logo --logo-x 10 --logo-y 10 --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/logo-tv.png --logo-opacity 200 /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00021.mp4` ... if I press ALT+C key combinations the logo appear on the top left but I try to fullscreen `cvlc --fullscreen --sub-source logo --logo-x 10 --logo-y 10 --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/logo-tv.png --logo-opacity 200 /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00021.mp4` with the combination ALT+C doesn't work ...

Comment: I try to set the logo in the GUI interface and set bottom-right. So next I try to launch vlc from command line...
a simple
`cvlc -f video.mp4`
now if I do ALT+C and ALT+F the logo appear. I try to search what I do so 
ALT + C = Crop one pixel from the bottom of the video
ALT + F = Crop one pixel from the right of the video
and the logo appear on the bottom right.

So how can do this in command line? There is no problem with the logo but only the right command. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy) with desktop, I enable FKMS and all works without any problem on my Raspberry 3b+. So the problem is the FKMS is not possible to enable in Debian version: 11 (bullseye). At now there are no problem with the logo and there are not dropped frames.
So the solution at now is enable the FKMS.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in a comment

`cvlc --sub-source logo --logo-x 10 --logo-y 10 --logo-file ./logo-stackoverflow.png --logo-opacity 100 your.mp4`

should display the logo

To activate the crop one pixel from the bottom of  the video, for cvlc
either:

> set `global-key-crop-bottom=Alt+c` in the vlc `vlcrc` configuration file

or:

> set it on the command line

`cvlc --sub-source logo --logo-x 10 --logo-y 10 --logo-file ./logo-stackoverow.png --logo-opacity 100 --global-key-crop-bottom=Alt+c --global-key-uncrop-bottom=Alt+Shift+c your.mp4`

For some weird reason it seems you must set the `--global-key` rather than just `--key`

Comment: I try `cvlc -f --sub-source logo --logo-file plogo-tv.png  --logo-position 10 --logo-opacity 256 6.mp4 -f --global-key-crop-bottom=Alt+c --global-key-uncrop-bottom=Alt+Shift+c
cvlc -f --sub-source logo --logo-file plogo-tv.png  --logo-position 10 --logo-opacity 256 6.mp4 -f --global-key-crop-bottom=Alt+c --global-key-crop-right=Alt+f
cvlc -f --sub-source logo --logo-file plogo-tv.png  --logo-position 10 --logo-opacity 256 6.mp4 -f --global-key-crop-bottom=Alt+c --global-key-uncrop-bottom=Alt+Shift+t+c --global-key-crop-right=Alt+f --global-key-uncrop-right=Alt+Shift+f` but never start logo.

Comment: Always I had to press Alt+c and Alt+f. I try in Mac vlc and I haven't problem. in raspberry it doesn't

Comment: Maybe can be helpful, I try to deactivate KMS in raspberry, and the "trick" ALT+c and ALT+f doesn't work

Comment: @pette "I've a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore.” you've lost me, I run Linux.

Comment: Hi, thanks but in the object of the post I wrote `Raspberry pi 3B+ bullseye` and `The png logo doesn't work with vlc and raspbian`